# Reaproveitamento do HttpClient e ciclo de vida de um ApiController

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, using

Com base [nesse site](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) e também em [algumas respostas do StackOverflow [en]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed) eu cheguei a conclusão de que não deveria usar a classe `HttpClient` em um bloco `using` apesar da mesma implementar `IDisposable`. Isso ajudaria no reaproveitamento do objeto já instanciado e traria melhorias de performance entre outras.

Mas considere o seguinte trecho de código:

```
public class MyServiceController : ApiController
{
    private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public void Post()
    {
        // ...
        var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://pt.stackoverflow.com");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Minha API está consumindo um outro serviço, mas se quando falamos do ciclo de vida do `MyServiceController`, não haveria reaproveitamento já que cada requisição do `Post` criará uma nova instância da classe, correto? Nesse caso eu poderia implementar normalmente usando o bloco `using`?

Comment: Se você torná-lo público e inicializar na startup

Comment: @LeandroAngelo obrigado por seu comentário. Deixando o `HttpClient` público na classe `startup` não poderia me trazer problemas se `MyServiceController` receber muitas requisições simultâneas?

Answer (score 2):

Eu criaria uma `BaseApiController` abstrata herdando a `ApiController` e adicionaria o `HttpClient` como público lá

```
public  abstract class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public static HttpClient meuHttpClient { get; set; }
}
```

E faria a inicialização no `_Application_Start()` da Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    BaseApiController.meuHttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
}
```

Assim você muda a herança das suas `Controllers` para a `BaseApiController` e poderá utilizar essa instância do HttpClient que foi incializado no início da aplicação.

```
public class MyServiceController : BaseApiController
{
    public void Post()
    {
        // ...
        var result = await meuHttpClient.GetAsync("https://pt.stackoverflow.com");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado por usa resposta, mas ainda estou com dúvidas quando a [esse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351630/reaproveitamento-do-httpclient-e-ciclo-de-vida-de-um-apicontroller?noredirect=1#comment705633_351630).